# Get title of currently playing video

Tags: javascript, jwplayer

Current I am working in codeigniter project, in that I need to integrate Jw player 5 with playlist. I just created plalist which are dynamic and its working fine. So, now I want get title or some other details of currently playing videos. I tried a lot, but no luck. I just posted here a bit of javascript code, I get that from Jw player sites forum, but it is not working for me. I just tried by static. Here is the code ..

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

        <div id="mediaplayer">
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://172.16.1.181:85/test/player1/jwplayer.js"></script>


            <script type="text/javascript">
                    jwplayer("mediaplayer").setup({
            flashplayer: "http://172.16.1.181:85/test/player1/player.swf",
                    height:"350",
                    width:"500",
                    autostart: "true",
                    'playlist': [{
            'file': 'http://172.16.1.181:85/test/flash/test.flv',
                    'image': 'http://172.16.1.181:85/test/images/no_image.gif',
                    'title': 'Test_video_1'
            },
            {
                'file': 'http://172.16.1.181:85/test/flash/test.flv',
                        'image': 'http://172.16.1.181:85/test/images/no_image.gif',
                        'title': 'Test_video_2'
                }
            ],
                    repeat: 'list'
            });

        </script>



<p>In the body:</p>
      <div id="nowplaying">

      <script type="text/javascript">
      jwplayer().getPlaylistItem().index
      </script>
      </div>


</html>
```

The player playing the video well. But I Dont know how to get currently playing video's details..Please help me guys..

Comment: Perhaps you could take a look here -> http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28851/javascript-api-reference

Comment: HI @PabloMescher..Thanks for your replay..I checked that link already..I used all functions they mentioned..But no luck..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 <div id="nowplaying">
    <script type="text/javascript">
       var current = jwplayer().getPlaylistItem();
       console.log(current.title);
    </script>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @alex. It worked. But made little changes with events.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use any third party frameworks to do this thing. You just need some some JavaScript basic functions...

```js
var video = document.getElementById('vid');
var video_src = video.src;
// The above code gets the source of video
var name_with_ext = video_src.split('/');
// This returns an array 
name_with_ext = name_with_ext[name_with_ext.length - 1];
// This returns the name of the file with the extension
var video_ext = name_with_ext.split('.');
// This returns an array too
video_ext = video_ext[video_ext.length -1];
// This returns the extension of video
var name = name_with_ext.replace(video_ext, '')
//This returns the name
```

```html
<video src="vid.mp4" id="vid" class="vid"></video>
```