# Display filename of currently playing item in JW PLAYER 6

Tags: php, flash, video, jwplayer, http-live-streaming

Im using http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1439570-example-loading-new-playlists this for updating the playlist via buttons , and need to display the currently playing file in an input box (for the viewer to copy) , I've tried the getPlayListItem() and had no luck ..  what i need is to display the Currently playing playlist , and once a user changes the playlist for it to display that one.. and vise-versa .

What could i do  to accomplish this?

Thanks.

Comment: What have you done so far ? Can you add some code and tell us exactly where is your problem ?

Comment: well im trying this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19999796/get-title-of-currently-playing-video to display the filename of the currently playing video , and it doesnt work . :( . what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

This is documented on the [JWplayer Javascript Api reference](http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1413089-javascript-api-reference),

```
.on('playlistItem')
```

> Fired when the playlist index changes to a new playlist item. This event occurs before the player begins playing the new playlist item.

**Event attributes:**

- `index (Number)`: Zero-based index into the playlist array (e.g. 0 is
  the first item).
- `playlist (Array)`: The new playlist; an array of playlist items.